# Multiple Quarto rendering issues when compared to Rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, rendering, quarto

I am atempting to switch from RMarkdown to Quarto, but I have several difficulties.

1. Can´t find tabset options (fade, pills)
2. CSS style does not seem to work properly on Quarto tabset - the element is always grey when active and only colored properly when inactive, despite the css style working properly in rmarkdown:

```
.nav>li>a{
    color: Grey;
}
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li.active>a, 
.nav>li.active>a:hover, .nav>li.active>a:focus{
    color: #BD3632;
}
```

3. Can´t find a way for quarto to render in current environment (using RStudio), thus already loaded objects are loaded again and again for each rendering. It adds time for large objects, if you need multiple renders to polish your report.
4. Date specified in yaml header is rendered in the wrong format:

```
date:               "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
```

results in
PUBLISHED
February 2, 2023

Comment: Quarto has its own option to format date (No need to use R!). Use [`date-format`](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/dates.html#using-a-date-format) to format the date.

Comment: You can not execute a quarto document in your current R environment. Each time it will be rendered in a new separate environment. For large file reading, you may try [`cache`](https://quarto.org/docs/projects/code-execution.html#cache).

Comment: And can you post a separate question about the tabset styling problem you are facing with a minimal reproducible example? You have too many **different!** question in one place. Or at least update this question with a minimal reproducible example?